# OSX related file creation

Tags: objective-c, macos, sandbox, nsfilecoordinator

I'm trying to build an application that easily converts from one file format to another. The idea is you drag the source file onto the dock tile and the output file is created alongside the source file (in the same directory.)

After reading the documentation, I have everything setup correctly -- I think... but it doesn't work.

My Info.plist contains the following:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            my_src_type
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        [...]
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            my_dest_type
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>NSIsRelatedItemType</key>
        <true/>
        [...]
    </dict>
</array>
```

If I'm reading the documentation correctly, this should allow my app to accept files of `my_src_type` via drag and drop and output files of `my_dest_type` in the same directory as the input file, provided of course that I let the sandbox know about it.

To that end, I have a `SimpleFilePresenter` that looks like this:

```
 @interface SimpleFilePresenter : NSObject<NSFilePresenter>
 @property (atomic, strong) NSURL *presentedItemURL;
 @property (atomic, strong) NSURL *primaryPresentedItemURL;
 @end

 @implementation SimpleFilePresenter
 - (NSOperationQueue *)presentedItemOperationQueue {
         return [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
 }
 @end
```

As soon as I use `addFilePresenter:` to request permission to create my output file, I get the following error in the Console.

```
2013-04-26 6:33:52.741 PM my_app[27639]: NSFileSandboxingRequestRelatedItemExtension: an error was received from pboxd instead of a token. Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code: 1
2013-04-26 6:33:52.741 PM my_app[27639]: +[NSFileCoordinator addFilePresenter:] could not get a sandbox extension. primaryPresentedItemURL: file://[...]/file.my_src_type, presentedItemURL: file://[...]/file.my_dest_type
```

Comment: Not an answer, but… I've found this stuff to be much easier to debug when using explicit `NSOpenPanel`/`NSSavePanel` instead of other open mechanism like dragging to the dock. You get more logging, more mysterious problems to search for when you do something wrong, and of course a much more obvious transition between your app and Powerbox.

Comment: Also, two things that may seem really stupid and shouldn't be relevant here, but… have you tried marking _both_ types as `NSIsRelatedItemType`, and/or changing your primary type from Viewer to Editor?

Comment: I just tried the two "stupid" ideas... unfortunately it didn't work. I'll need to fiddle a bit with my code to use an NSOpenPanel instead of drag and drop. Hopefully that will be helpful.

Comment: Took less time than expect to use NSOpenPanel, but not change at all in the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `addFilePresenter:` is ***not*** synchronous or instantaneous.
All I had to do was call `[NSFileCoordinator filePresenters]` after `addFilePresenter:` which seems to have the effect of blocking until all file presenters are ready to go.

Also, I'm using Qt, so I was pleasantly surprised that this all works without needing to get specially created `NSURL` objects from the more scary looking `NSFileCoordinator` methods.

Comment: That `[NSFileCoordinator filePresenters]` use seems like something that works "by accident". A safer way is probably to coordinate the writing: use `[NSFileCoordinator initWithFilePresenter]` to create a coordinator and call its `coordinateWritingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:` to write the file. That works even without calling `filePresenters` first.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for this error might be an incorrect or missing UTI definition in the project info file.

A UTI must be defined to the document type and it should be identical to UTI defined  imported/exported UTIs section (if it's not a built-in UTI).

Comment: Can a UTI be used in the info.plist, or should an extension be used there?